# What are the red lines for?

Tags: terraria

I was digging underground in Terraria and when I was mining some stone, I noticed they had red spots on them called Active Stone Blocks. When I had it in my characters hand, there were red lines starting to go down the tunnel I was going down through. What are these red lines?

I'm a beginner of Terraria, so I don't know much about this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those red lines are wire, which is used to connect triggers and mechanisms. Wire is invisible unless you're holding something that can interact with it, like the Active Stone Block, which becomes non-solid when activated by wire. In the underground, you will usually find it connecting pressure plates to various traps. You can [check the wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wire) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just a beginner at Terraria, and I don't know much about wiring. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: And if you see it underground, and you didn't put it there - its probably a trap... so watch out ;)

Comment: @JimJones Use it as a trap finder- many a time I would of died, if it weren't for my wrench and light. (Sorry for trying to rhyme, I don't do it most of the time)

Comment: I know. The boulder traps (that's what I learned) I will avoid.

Answer (score -4):

Sometimes they hold boulders, and when you're underneath the trap, the active block moves, and it drops the boulder. I'm guessing you dug through a boulder trap.

Comment: @9t. He did provide an answer (the red lines hold boulders). If it's wrong no need to flag it as "Not an answer", it's still an answer, just a wrong one

Comment: @Oak I may or may not have forgotten to read the whole question since I was in a rush. Apologies.